# Key cancellation form in lilypond

Tags: lilypond

I have key changing example:

```
\score {
\relative c'' {
  \key bes \major
  g1
  \key g \major
  g1
}
}
```

It produces:

[image]

But i would like to have another template for this: first 2 becars, then staff bar, then sharp. Like this:

[image]

This is just another tradition. Does it possible in lilypond ?

---

### Possible solutions

One solution is to force key to c major, add empty bar and only then change key to g major. (Thanks to "@mack" from #lilypond@irc.libera.chat)

```
\relative c'' {
  \key bes \major
  g1

  \key c \major \bar ""
  s16
  \bar "|"

  \key g \major 
  g1
}
```

Unfortunately, there is extra space between bar and becars:

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

This override solve my problem:

```
 \override Score.BreakAlignment.break-align-orders=
  #(vector '(
             left-edge
             staff-ellipsis
             cue-end-clef
             ambitus
             breathing-sign
             signum-repetitionis
             clef
             cue-clef
             key-cancellation
             staff-bar
             key-signature
             time-signature
             custos)
           '(left-edge
                  staff-ellipsis
                  cue-end-clef
                  ambitus
                  breathing-sign
                  signum-repetitionis
                  clef
                  cue-clef
                  key-cancellation
                  staff-bar
                  key-signature
                  time-signature
                  custos)
           '(
             left-edge
             staff-ellipsis
             ambitus
             breathing-sign
             signum-repetitionis
             clef
             key-cancellation
             key-signature
             time-signature
             staff-bar
             cue-clef
             custos))
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the possible solution in your question:

1. Make the spacer rest into a grace note, i.e. `\grace {s16}`.
2. Use `\once\hide Score.BarLine` instead of `\bar ""`.  This is better because it *hides* rather than *omits* the barline; there will still be *some* space around the cancellation of the key signature.
   If you use `\bar ""` with a more densely packed bar then the cancellation of the key signature can overlap with the notes.

```
\relative c'' {
    \key g \minor
        g1 |
        
    \once\hide Score.BarLine
    \key c \major
        \grace {s16} 
    \bar "|"
    
    \key g \major
        g1 |
}
```

[image: Key signature cancellation appears before the barline without unnecessary spacing]